# State Data gets overwritten in Microsoft Bot Framework for multiple conversations

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot

I have built a bot in NodeJS using Microsoft Bot Framework and deployed it on a remote server. I am connecting to the bot from my local machine using Bot-Emulator and ngrok to receive the response. When I connect to the bot from 2 separate machines simultaneously, the state data gets overwritten and I get the same response for different IDs.
I have tried to generate a random id using UUID to distinguish between the conversations and also tried to store the userID separately for different sessions but it isn't working for me. 
Is there a way to for the bot to treat each instance as a separate session or just not overwrite the user data and store it separately so that it can give me the correct response for both queries? Thanks a lot.

```js
bot.dialog('/employee', [
    function (session) {
        session.send("Welcome to the information portal.");
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please provide the Network ID");
        console.log(session.message.address.conversation.id);
    },
    function (session, results) {
        //console.log(sessionid);
                session.userData.employeeID = results.response;
                session.endDialog("What information would you like for the employee?");
                console.log(session.message.address.conversation.id);
    }
])

bot.dialog('/email', [
    function (session) {
        const https = require("https");
        const url =
            "https://**********" + session.userData.employeeID;
        https.get(url, res => {
            res.setEncoding("utf8");
            let body = "";
            res.on("data", data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(
                    `${body[0]['****]} is working in ${body[0]['****']}.`,
                );
                session.send(`${body[0]['****']}'s email ID is ${body[0]['****']}.`);
                console.log(session.message.address.conversation.id);
                console.log(session.userData.employeeID);
                console.log(session.userData);
                var msg = `I hope your query was fulfilled. Thank you.`;
                session.endConversation(msg);
            });
        });
    }
])
```

Comment: As far as I know, your user Id cannot be setup on Bot-Emulator so your bot will receive the same user Id for 2 users of the emulator, hence the problem. You will not have this problem on real channels (except webchat if you don't overwrite the default one, which is quite easy)

Comment: ^this is the answer